# ng-click to execute after ng-model changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

I was wondering if there was a way I could have a ng-click function which takes in a scope variable execute after the value of the ng-model of that same scope variable changes. I have a list of `analysis` objects in a list called `analyses` that have (among others) an `include` boolean attribute. They are displayed in html as button checkboxes to press to include/exclude.

I have this html:

```
Number of bisulfite sequences: {{included}} used / {{excluded}} excluded
<div ng-repeat="analysis in analyses"><br><label class="btn btn-success" 
ng-model="analysis.include" ng-click="set(analysis.include)" btn-checkbox>
```

This is the code in the controller:

```
$scope.analyses = some_list_of_analyses
$scope.included = 0
$scope.excluded = $scope.analyses.length

$scope.set = function(include){

//more code to execute involving $scope.analyses

  if(include){
    $scope.included += 1
    $scope.excluded -= 1
  }
  else{
    $scope.excluded += 1
    $scope.included -= 1
  }
}
```

right now, assuming I start with a list of analyses that are all excluded as you can see in the initialization, when I click on a button, it should increase the `included` scope variable by one and decrease the `excluded` by one. instead, it passes in `analysis.include` before the variable actually changes so the first button I click shows -1 used / n+1 excluded.

The solutions I can think of are either to find some way of having ng-click execute after the scope variable is bound after ng-model, or some way to change $scope.analyses objects within the ng-click method, so then the ng-model statement isn't needed?

Thanks!

EDIT: the ng-model statement is actually needed for the btn-checkbox directive. I need this directive to show a toggle on/off for including/excluding certain analyses. Alternative directives or code to implement css for indicating inclusion/exclusion would be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if instead of passing in the analysis.included you get it from the scope in your function

I created a  [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/nOEzGzyGuSC7vR0WwK7r?p=preview) to demonstrate

basically HTML:

```
 Number of bisulfite sequences: {{included}} used / {{excluded}} excluded

<div ng-repeat="analysis in analyses">
  <br />
  <label class="btn btn-success" ng-model="analysis.include"  btn-checkbox>
    <button ng-click="set($index)">Click Me!</button>
  </label>
</div>
```

So here, you pass in the $index so you know which one to look at on $scope in the controller. so then in your controller:

```
$scope.set = function(i){

 var include = $scope.analyses[i].include;
 //more code to execute involving $scope.analyses

 if(include){
  $scope.included += 1
  $scope.excluded -= 1
 }
 else{
  $scope.excluded += 1
  $scope.included -= 1
 }
};
```

It seemed to work in the plunkr. the included went up and the excluded went down

Update: New [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/nOEzGzyGuSC7vR0WwK7r?p=preview) that toggles included/excluded instead of only incrementing.

As well as updated set function:

```
$scope.set = function(i){

 $scope.analyses[i].include = !$scope.analyses[i].include;

 include = $scope.analyses[i].include

 //more code to execute involving $scope.analyses

if(include){
  $scope.included += 1
  $scope.excluded -= 1
 } else {
  $scope.excluded += 1
  $scope.included -= 1
 }
};
```

Comment: I accidentally made a type in the plunkr for $scope.analysis. the 2nd item in the array says "inlude" instead of "include" but it still works as expected, since include isn't true, the counters go the opposite way as the first button

Comment: the buttons should toggle (so if you include it, you can click it again to exclude it), but it looks like your plunker just increments. maybe i wasn't clear in the question, apologies

Comment: I updated my answer to make it toggle instead of only increment

Comment: it's just an addition of one line in the javascript then, right? Yes I solved it using that way too - except i used a different variable for the ng-model because it still executed the set function before the ng-model (and therefore there could be no changes because include would toggle twice every single time I clicked a button). Your plunkr demonstrates a working solution though!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not *quite* sure I follow, but I think we can simplify things.

First, let's say that each `analysis` has a property called `included`.

This allows you to write a couple methods like this:

```
$scope.included = function() {
  var count = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < $scope.analyses.length; i++) {
    if($scope.analyses[i].included) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
};

$scope.excluded = function() {
  var count = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < $scope.analyses.length; i++) {
    if(!$scope.analyses[i].included) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
};
```

I'll let you do the refactoring to keep it DRY. Then your UI can do something like this:

```
Number of bisulfite sequences: {{included()}} used / {{excluded()}} excluded
<div ng-repeat="analysis in analyses"><br>
<label class="btn btn-success" ng-model="analysis" ng-click="set(analysis)" btn-checkbox>
```

And your click can be very simple (note that we are now passing in the analysis object, you can remove the `ng-model` attribute):

```
$scope.set = function(analysis) {
  $scope.analysis.included = !$scope.analysis.included;
};
```

Comment: You're right. I didn't even notice that directive. That's a directive you wrote? I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I'm trying to think about it more too using this kind of logic for the included/excluded variables...
And I didn't write the directive, it's an angular directive I found here: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/buttons

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to alter the way you are tracking the included / excluded values.

If, instead of adding/subtracting from values you simply track the length of the array then everything should fall into place.

Here is what I'm talking about.  Your HTML could look like this:

```
<div ng-controller="solutionController">
Number of bisulfite sequences: {{included.length}} used / {{analyses.length - included.length}} excluded
<div ng-repeat="analysis in analyses">
    <br />
    <label class="btn btn-success" ng-click="include(analysis)" btn-checkbox=""></label>
</div>
```

And your controller could look something like this:

```
angular.module("routerApp").controller("solutionController", ["$scope", function($scope){
    $scope.included = [];
    $scope.analyses = ["sodium", "sulfur", "calcium"];

    $scope.include = function(includeMe){
        $scope.included.push(includeMe);
    };

}]);
```

I mean I don't know exactly what your analyses objects look like etc, but this should get you up and running on binding those counts to the actual array lengths.

Comment: and as a side note:  you could easily mark items as included in the array by setting "includeMe.included = true" inside of your include function and then using a filter on the ng-repeat so that only analyses without "included=true" display.

Comment: thanks, although my analysis objects are fairly large, i'm not sure if creating another list to store them would be the best use of space, but I could just add the name or something to the included list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow but your conditional logic in `$scope.set` is looking for a true value before the include property is increased. This is clearly not happening as demonstrated [in this plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/twh2JnJiDHuF6Vy3XUox/preview) example of your code in action.

The only difference is that I have made sure that `include` is a property of the first three analysis && set to `true`. Your code is working as expected, your analysis objects are not.